# ImportError: No module named citations

Tags: python, importerror

I use tethne package for my research of network analysis.
But, I hit the snag after getting error in it.

This is my input script

```
import tethne 
import tethne.readers as rd
from tethne.readers import wos
papers = rd.wos.read("/Users/Documents/AI_Edu/savedrecs/savedrecs (1).txt")
papers[0]
import tethne.networks as nt
BC = nt.citations.bibliographic_coupling(papers)
BC
```

and this is what i got

`Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "/Users/PycharmProjects/network2/network2.py", line 7, in <module>

    import citations as citations
    ImportError: No module named citations`

It seems like there is no module names "citations" but, I downloaded the full package and the procedure was exact copy I was guided by this package developers, though it was long time ago and no more updates on it.

What is wrong with it?